# Oauth2 + Spring Boot resource for everyone

Tags: spring, angular, api, security, oauth-2.0

I have my Spring Boot app (Rest api app) protected with `Oauth2`. This app has resources available for everyone (for not sign in users) and for auth users (who need access token). This API is used by my `Angular 2+` website. There is my question, how to prevent other clients from using my (not needed access token) resource API? I would like use my `API` only by my Angular website.

If you have any tutorials, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no fool proof solution. I have tried in past to protect the public apis by the checking the referer header. Requests originating from your website will have the referer header set as your domain name.

```
referer: https://stackoverflow.com/
```

Comment: This will be ok. Thank you